# text indicating the number of items selected on Datatable Flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I will want to know how to change the text indicative of the number of selected element on a Datatable.
Hi, I would like to know how to change the text indicating the number of elements selected on a Datatable.
Instead of this "1 item selected" I would like to have this "1 delivery selected".

My DataTableSource code :

```
    class DeliveryTableSource extends DataTableSource {
  List<RequestDeliverySource> _list;
  int _rowSelectedCount = 0;

  DeliveryTableSource(this._list);

  @override
  DataRow getRow(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index > _list.length)
      return null;
    else {
      RequestDeliverySource source = _list[index];
      return DataRow.byIndex(
          cells: buildCells(source),
          index: index,
          selected: source.isSelected,
          onSelectChanged: (bool value) {
            if (source.isSelected != value) {
              _rowSelectedCount += value ? 1 : -1;
              source.isSelected = value;
              notifyListeners();
            }
          });
    }
  }

  List<DataCell> buildCells(RequestDeliverySource source) {
    return [
      DataCell(Text("${source.name}")),
      DataCell(Text("${source.deliveryAddress}")),
      DataCell(Text("${source.pickupAddress}")),
      DataCell(Text("${source.plannedDeliveryDate}")),
      DataCell(Text("${source.effectiveDeliveryDate}")),
      DataCell(Text("${source.showStatus()}"))
    ];
  }

  void selectedAll(bool checked) {
    _list.forEach((source) {
      source.isSelected = checked;
    });
    _rowSelectedCount = checked ? _list.length : 0;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  @override
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;

  @override
  int get rowCount => _list.length;

  @override
  int get selectedRowCount => _rowSelectedCount;
}
```

My component widget Table :

```
class DeliveryTable extends StatefulWidget {
  DeliveryTable({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new DeliveryTableState();
  }
}

class DeliveryTableState extends State<DeliveryTable> {
  int _rowsPerPage = 10;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    RequestDelivery delivery = new RequestDelivery();
    delivery.name = "livraison test";
    RequestDeliverySource source = new RequestDeliverySource(delivery);
    DeliveryTableSource tableSource = new DeliveryTableSource([source]);
    return Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: PaginatedDataTable(
                header: Text("Livraison effectuée",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0)),
                rowsPerPage: _rowsPerPage,
                onSelectAll: tableSource.selectedAll,
                onRowsPerPageChanged: (int value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _rowsPerPage = value;
                  });
                },
                columns: _buildColumns(),
                source: tableSource)));
  }

  List<DataColumn> _buildColumns() {
    return [
      DataColumn(label: Text("Nom"), tooltip: "Nom de la livraison"),
      DataColumn(
          label: Text("Lieux de livraison"), tooltip: "Adresse de livraison"),
      DataColumn(
          label: Text("Lieux de ramassage"), tooltip: "Adresse de ramassage"),
      DataColumn(
          label: Text("Date de livraison"), tooltip: "Date de livraison"),
      DataColumn(
          label: Text("Livrée le"), tooltip: "Date de livraison effective"),
      DataColumn(label: Text("Statut"), tooltip: "Statu de la livraison")
    ];
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: show us the code you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because the `PaginatedDataTable` will replace the header if the count is bigger than 0 from the source provided. To bypass this, you can create your own header and your own getter in your `DataTableSource`.

[image]

```
class DataTable extends StatefulWidget {
  _DataTableState createState() => _DataTableState();
}

class _DataTableState extends State<DataTable> {
  final source = MySource();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PaginatedDataTable(
      columns: <DataColumn>[
        DataColumn(
          label: Text('Label'),
        ),
      ],
      header: Container(
        child: Text('I have ${source.selectedItems} deliveries selected.'),
      ),
      source: source,
    );
  }
}

class MySource extends DataTableSource {
  @override
  DataRow getRow(int index) {
    return DataRow(
      cells: <DataCell>[
        DataCell(
          Text('New cell'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  int get selectedItems => 20; // Create your own counter

  @override
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;

  @override
  int get rowCount => 10;

  @override
  int get selectedRowCount => 0; // You want to keep this at zero
}
```